# How to upgrade pip from 22.2 to 22.3 on mac M1

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I want to install tensorflow on my mac, but it require the pip version above 22.3, my pip version is 22.2.2 and cannot upgrade to 22.3

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (22.2.2)
```

and try to upgrade with specified version

```
$ pip install --upgrade 'pip==22.3' 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip==22.3 (from versions: 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5.1, 0.6, 0.6.1, 0.6.2, 0.6.3, 0.7, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.8, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 6.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 7.0.0, 7.0.1, 7.0.2, 7.0.3, 7.1.0, 7.1.1, 7.1.2, 8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.1.0, 8.1.1, 8.1.2, 9.0.0, 9.0.1, 9.0.2, 9.0.3, 10.0.0b1, 10.0.0b2, 10.0.0, 10.0.1, 18.0, 18.1, 19.0, 19.0.1, 19.0.2, 19.0.3, 19.1, 19.1.1, 19.2, 19.2.1, 19.2.2, 19.2.3, 19.3, 19.3.1, 20.0, 20.0.1, 20.0.2, 20.1b1, 20.1, 20.1.1, 20.2b1, 20.2, 20.2.1, 20.2.2, 20.2.3, 20.2.4, 20.3b1, 20.3, 20.3.1, 20.3.2, 20.3.3, 20.3.4, 21.0, 21.0.1, 21.1, 21.1.1, 21.1.2, 21.1.3, 21.2, 21.2.1, 21.2.2, 21.2.3, 21.2.4, 21.3, 21.3.1, 22.0, 22.0.1, 22.0.2, 22.0.3, 22.0.4, 22.1b1, 22.1, 22.1.1, 22.1.2, 22.2, 22.2.1, 22.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip==22.3
```

the version list show me that 22.2.2 is the lastest version of pip. and I am tried to use pip with `python -m` prefix, `python -m pip install tensorflow`, `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` ... and all the same result.

How can I upgrade it?

My environment:

```
python: 3.8 (with venv)
pip: 22.2
macos: 12.0.1
```

Comment: why do you need/want to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions given below to install TensorFlow on M1 mac.

**Step 1**

Download conda environment from this [link](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh)

**Step 2: Run the downloaded script and activate conda**

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
sh ~/Downloads/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
source ~/miniforge3/bin/activate
```

**Step 3: Install TensorFlow dependencies**

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
```

**Step 4: Install base TensorFlow**

Do this step inside the virtual environment that you have created

```
pip install tensorflow-macos
```

**Step 5: Verify Installation**

```
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

For more info: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/